# Hide call screen on Android

Tags: android, broadcast

i would like to hide the call screen when receiving incoming call. I use broadcast receiver (PHONE_STATE) but it's a non-ordered broadcast so i can't use abortbroadcast().

Is there any other solution to hide the call screen or the switch from a non-ordered broadcast to an ordered one ?

Here is my manifest :

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <receiver android:name=".PhoneCallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="99999" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call screen cannot be closed or aborted, it can only be hidden behind a different full-screen one.

If you go down this route, be aware that there will always be a delay between the call being received and you receiving the broadcast, so the original call screen might be briefly visible.

Comment: thanks Delyan. and is it possible to hide the icon on the notification bar ?

Comment: You can't cancel other apps' notifications. You can, however, hide the notification bar entirely.

Comment: How can I hide the notification bar ?